# Why do my cinematics end abruptly?

Tags: technical-issues, saints-row-the-third

I've noticed that some of my cinematics, as well as dialogue, seem to be ending abruptly. To the point that I'm wondering if it might be a glitch. I've had sentences cut short in the middle of a word. Same with the cinematics. Also, I've noticed that there are times when I'm probably 75-100ft away from my objective marker, and it will trigger the next cut scene.

What can I do about it?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I couldn't think of a way to word the question. Now it seems so obvious though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug.

I get this as well. After the first chapter I am not sure what happened to the bad guy leader. I sometimes die when I reach an objective e.g. when my guy gets out of his car in the set piece his car lands on him and he dies.

Hopefully they patch it.

Comment: What you describe is also something different, I think: not all game action stops when a cutscene is played. I think this depends on exactly what is happening. For example, during Mayhem, as soon as you complete the sequence, all your notoriety goes away, but objects recently blown up remain present, as well as some officers and gang members ... and a last-second shot might be fired during Mayhem, but get resolved afterward. I had one instance where I fired a rocket at a helicopter, finished Mayhem before it struck ... and ended up with 4 stars of notoriety for hitting the helicopter.

Comment: @DaveDuPlantis, I said I also get the same problems as the OP and also get some other weird stuff around the objective cut scenes. I probably could have broken my post better into another paragraph.